# How can I keep track of the number of bytes written to an std::ostream object?

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

I want to write a bunch of data to an `ostream` object and return the number of bytes written. For example:

```
using namespace std;
size_t writeStuffToStream(ostream &stream)
{
    stream << some_string << some_integer << some_other_arbitrary_object << endl;
    return number_of_bytes_written;
}
```

There is the obvious workaround of writing everything to a `stringstream` and getting the byte count out of that, and then writing the `stringstream` to the stream, but that takes extra time and memory.

I also realize that if if all the data I wanted to write were preexisting strings, then there would be no problem. It's `some_integer` and `some_other_arbitrary_object` that are the problem.

Comment: you can chain streambuf objects, so you can derive a counting streambuf from std::streambuf. in it, delegate operations to the original streambuf after recording the counter info. There's a nice tutorial here: http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ostream` [`tellp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/tellp/) method.

Note that this might fail if the provided `ostream` does not support positions. In that case you can create a temporary `ostringstream` to format your data, then extract the `string`, get its length and send it to the input `ostream`.

You can probably also write a custom `ostream` that send to another `ostream` and count emitted characters. I expected to find a virtual method to override in ostream to write just characters, but I did not find it :( You can re-use the stringstream code and replace the buffer writes to writes to an other ostream. `string-stream.cc` is about 500 lines long, so that's not this bad.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little put off by the fact that `tellp()` is not guaranteed to work for all objects. And I already mentioned that I don't want to have to create an intermediate `stringstream`. How would I create a custom `ostream` that can count the bytes written, if I can't count the bytes written in the first place?